# JS/HTML Date picker enforce rule to ensure input is today

Tags: javascript, html, validation

When creating a date picker, I have it set to only allow today onwards. which works... But it appears that the user can then tab into the field and change the date to "before" today. Is there a way to enforce the "must be today or future date" rule?

Here is my example;

```js
var today = new Date();
var d = today.getDate();
var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
var y = today.getFullYear();
if (d < 10) {
  d = '0' + d
}
if (m < 10) {
  m = '0' + m
}

today = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
document.getElementById("datePicker").setAttribute("min", today);
```

```html
<input id="datePicker" type='date' >
```

Comment: If you're using a server, just make your life easier by doing specific validation server-side. Anything on the frontend can be modified by the user.

Comment: You could write a module... and call it on an onchange of the date picker to do client side validation, but at the end of the day, any one can open a console, find the function and remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use EventListener to listen and set the value of your input to today date when entered value is lower than today

```js
    var today = new Date();
    var d = today.getDate();
    var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    if (d < 10) {
      d = '0' + d
    }
    if (m < 10) {
      m = '0' + m
    }

    today = y + '-' + m + '-' + d;
    const input = document.getElementById("datePicker")
    input.setAttribute("min", today);

    input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      const d1 = new Date(today);
      const d2 = new Date(event.target.value);
      if(d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()){
        event.target.value = today
      }
    });
```

```html
<input id="datePicker" type='date'>
```

Comment: Thats perfect... Could I ask though, what is the `const same = d1.getTime() === d2.getTime();` line for? I can't see that variable used anywhere?

Comment: (^_^) sorry it's just a mistake, let me remove it